# Change DIV content using ajax, php and jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div which contains some text for the database:

```
<div id="summary">Here is summary of movie</div>
```

And list of links:

```
<a href="?id=1" class="movie">Name of movie</a>
<a href="?id=2" class="movie">Name of movie</a>
..
```

The process should be something like this:

1. Click on the link
2. Ajax using the url of the link to pass data via GET to php file / same page
3. PHP returns string
4. The div is changed to this string

Comment: Are you using some js framework such as jQuery or you want a plain javascript soultion?

Comment: Change the contents of a div using `$('#summary').html("Your text");`

Comment: @Eamorr - but how can I pass the get request?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
<script>

function getSummary(id)
{
   $.ajax({

     type: "GET",
     url: 'Your URL',
     data: "id=" + id, // appears as $_GET['id'] @ your backend side
     success: function(data) {
           // data is ur summary
          $('#summary').html(data);
     }

   });

}
</script>
```

And add `onclick` event in your lists

```
<a onclick="getSummary('1')">View Text</a>
<div id="#summary">This text will be replaced when the onclick event (link is clicked) is triggered.</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You could achieve this quite easily with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) by registering for the click event of the anchors (with class="movie") and using the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to send an AJAX request and replace the contents of the summary div:

```
$(function() {
    $('.movie').click(function() {
        $('#summary').load(this.href);

        // it's important to return false from the click
        // handler in order to cancel the default action
        // of the link which is to redirect to the url and
        // execute the AJAX request
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: But I need to pass a GET request, there isn't each summary a page.. there is a php file which gets an ID of the movie and draw the summary  from the database. :-)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
   function getmoviename(id)
   {    
     var p_url= yoururl from where you get movie name,
     jQuery.ajax({
     type: "GET",             
     url: p_url,
     data: "id=" + id,
      success: function(data) {
       $('#summary').html(data);

    }
 });    
 }
```

and you html part is

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="movie" onclick="getmoviename(youridvariable)">
  Name of movie</a>

  <div id="summary">Here is summary of movie</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me and you don't need the inline script:

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showme').bind('click', function() {

        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        var num=$(this).attr("class");
        var poststr="request="+num+"&moreinfo="+id;
        $.ajax({
              url:"testme.php",
              cache:0,
              data:poststr,
              success:function(result){
                     document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML=result;
               }
        }); 
    });
 });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class='request_1 showme' id='rating_1'>More stuff 1</div>
    <div class='request_2 showme' id='rating_2'>More stuff 2</div>
    <div class='request_3 showme' id='rating_3'>More stuff 3</div>

    <div id="stuff">Here is some stuff that will update when the links above are clicked</div>
```

The request is sent to testme.php:

```
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Pragma: nocache");

    $request_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_REQUEST['request']);
    $request_moreinfo = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_REQUEST['moreinfo']);

    if($request_id=="1")
    {
        echo "show 1";
    }
    elseif($request_id=="2")
    {
        echo "show 2";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "show 3";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#summary').load('ajax.php', function() {
  alert('Loaded.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.movie').click(function(){
        var this_href=$(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url:this_href,
            type:'post',
            cache:false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#summary').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function getSummary(id)
{
   $.ajax({

     type: "GET",//post
     url: 'Your URL',
     data: "id="+id, // appears as $_GET['id'] @ ur backend side
     success: function(data) {
           // data is ur summary
          $('#summary').html(data);
     }

   });

}
</script>
```