# load/refresh a div from a link in a google maps infowindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps, html

I have a google maps v3 map with multiple markers, each has an info window with a link inside.  The link itself is created dynamically from the map init function read from an xml file.

I can make the link open a new page without issues, passing the parameter of the marker as a query string for the php page.  I can also make an external link on the page refresh the content of a div but not pass the query string parameter out of google maps.

What I want to do is for the link in the infowindow to be clicked which will load another div on the same page with content called from an external php file passing the query string as a parameter.

This creates the link in the infowindow:

```
if (markers[i].getAttribute("mtype")=='Malware'){
              if (markers[i].getAttribute("amount")<10){var cimg = new google.maps.MarkerImage("msmall.png");}
              if (markers[i].getAttribute("amount")>20){var cimg = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mmed.png");}                          if (markers[i].getAttribute("amount")>50){var cimg = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mlarge.png");}
              var links = '<a href="#" id="ipdetail">IP Details</a>';  
          }
```

This is the code to update the div: (at present with a hardcoded parameter)

```
<script> $(function() {
    $('a[href=#]').click(function() {
        $('#udt').load('whois.php?208.73.210.29');
        return false;
    }); }); </script>
```

Thanks for any help, I've searched and searched but havent actually been able to find anything about dynamically updating an external div from within a google maps infowindow.  My best guess is that I have to pass the link click event through the DOM handler in some way but being relatively new to jscript and jquery, I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery) just like this?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else needs this, I've managed to find a solution.

Put the script to call the external within a function and append an on click event to the link to call the function.  It works fine.

```
var links = '<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="markup();">IP Details</a>';

function markup(){
$(function() {
        $('#udt').load('whois.php?208.73.210.29');
        return false;
});
}
```

Where #udt is the name of your div.