# php mathquestion captcha, ajax refresh button

Tags: php, ajax, captcha

I have these two sessions vars on my php that generate a random number:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['num1']) && !isset($_SESSION['num2'])) {
$_SESSION['num1'] = rand(1,5);
$_SESSION['num2'] = rand(1,5);
}
?>
```

And on the same page I have this label that shows num1 + num2:

```
<label><?=$_SESSION['num1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['num2']?> ?</label>
```

What I would like to do is to turn the img that is right on the side of the label into a link, that will update num1 and num2 vars without refreshing the page, is it possible?

Should i create those vars in a separeted file like captcha.php, and then include it on the label showing the generated numbers with an echo on captcha.php or something like that?
Or do I need to use ajax?

Can you guys give me a hand on this, i'm designer, trying to create a portfolio, and this form is driving me crazy!
Thanks

---

@Koterpillar
As you said, on my captcha.php i would have these:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['num1']) && !isset($_SESSION['num2'])) {
$_SESSION['num1'] = rand(1,5);
$_SESSION['num2'] = rand(1,5);
}
?>
```

Then i will include the captcha php into a div lets say #captcha. The captcha is done with a simple question like 1+3=, there is no drawing image or anything like that, its a small webpage, i think i wont need those noise and lines on the captcha, the validation is made on php submit form. but how to call the captcha php with ajax to update that div? Its something like this?

```
$("#captcha").click(function() {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "includes/captcha.php",
data: ,
success: function(){

},
});
}
```

Thanks for you help!!

Comment: ajax is the right idea..BTW do you use jquery ?

Comment: yes i'm using jquery and php only... but i think i will need this ajax thing! Or theres is another solution? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Ajax if you want to "update num1 and num2 without refreshing the page". Suggest something like:

```
<div id='captcha'><?php include 'captcha.php'; ?></div>
```

and then Ajax-updating `captcha` `div` by requesting the same `captcha.php`:

```
$.get('includes/captcha.php', function (data) {
    $('#captcha').html(data);
});
```

(Obviously, rate-limiting, drawing the image, etc. is still needed.)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Koterpillar, i really appreciated!! Could you help me writing this ajax updating if you have time? I'll edit my question so you can lead me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Session will run on one time... that mean when you open the page if session is set.... then set the session values and check the session values...  I think you need to update your page after the loading .... then you need to use Ajax...That beacons session is server side.. without server request you can't set or get values from session..

Thank you...

Comment: Thansk for you reply @D.d.Tharanga! Unfortunately, i tryed, but i couldn't understand what you said. Its kind hard for a designer with no knowledge on php, ajax, jquery, to do something like that. But thanks man, i really appreciated your reply. if you could give some examples i don't know, maybe it would get easier :D

Comment: I think this link help u to find the details ....   http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp                        http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want updates without refreshing the page, then yes, you need to use Ajax.