# How do I change the text of a paragraph using servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a paragraph with `id = story` and I want to change its text dynamically using a servlet. How do I do this? I'm new and using `getWriter().println()` seems to create a new document instead of appending to the existing one.
Thanks

Comment: If you want 'dynamic' you need to look to JS/AJAX/JQuery.

Comment: In jQuery, a JavaScript library, it would be like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery).

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer - you can't.

Server-side code cannot change a response which has already been sent to the client.
To change text inside an HTML tag, use Javascript on the browser.

See http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Hmm Alright thanks. I began to suspect this when an hour of Google search yielded no results.

Comment: A useful analogy would be: you sending someone an email with a document attached, and then try to change the document after they've received it. Clearly you can't do this. On the other hand, with AJAX, the analogy would be: the recipient asks you what changes need to be made, you send another email with the changes, and the recipient then modifies the document himself. That's OK.