# Updating contents of specific div element only

Tags: jquery, html, web

I am new to web development. I am developing a page and its broken down to various div elements. In order to decrease the data consumption, i want to update the contents of only a specific div element on trigger of any event and rest should be the same. How can I achieve that?

[edit] [code]

```
<html>
....
....
 <body>
    <div id="post">
        <h1>Post tile<h1>
        <img src="/s/smt.png">
         <p>this is the post desc</p>
    <div>
<div id="any other">
</div>
. 
. 
.
 <body>
</html>
```

Lets consider the above case where I am in need to dynamically update div "post" only without querying any other portion of the page.

important edit (@Milind Anantwar, thanks for making this comment):
The update should be dependent to server. I mean, situation like I need to update that div from my database..

Comment: Plz show your code. 
Suggestion , you can use javascript (jquery) to do it

Comment: @beck03076 "I don't know web programming" doesn't mean I don't know linux :)

Comment: from where are you planning to update that div. should it be from server side on just js script

Comment: Ajax ? [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064666/update-div-with-jquery-ajax-response-html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, it should from server side

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/oZOvEVus/1/edit)**:

```
var button = document.getElementById('b');
var div = document.getElementById('any_other');

var count = 0;
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Updating div dynamically by click event on button
  div.innerHTML = 'This is dynamicaaly updated - ' + count + ' times';
  count++;
});
```

Comment: I want it to update from server, at such case, what i am to do?:?

Comment: @devifox you should read about ajax. Use ajax, fetch the content, update div with the response...