# Render partial view from another partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to render a partial view with an ActionResult controller which returns a partial. I need to pass a userid to the controller. The view I am rendering it in has a controller of its own and is a partial view as well. Below is how I am calling it in view,

```
 @Html.Action("MultipleApplicationDetail", "ApplicationDetail", new { UserID = Model.UserDetail.UserID });
```

The view gets generated but not the partial view. Am i calling it worng.

EDIT

The action returns a lits of applications. below is the code

```
    public ActionResult MultipleApplicationDetail(int UserID, int? page)
    {

        IList<ApplicationDetailViewModel> applicationmodellist = new List<ApplicationDetailViewModel>();




        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
        if (GetApplicationList(UserID) > 1)
        {



            applicationmodellist = GetAllApplications(UserID);
            applicationmodellist = applicationmodellist.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);


        }

            return PartialView("_MultipleApplicationDetail", applicationmodellist);


    }
```

Comment: Since nobody can possibly know what that action does, nobody can answer this question.

Comment: i have added the action code

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `HTML.RenderAction` method into your partial view.

Or do it with JavaScript and AJAX call.

see: [Change DIV content using ajax, php and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery)