# Changing PHP variables after DOM load, will changes reflect?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I was asked a question by a friend and I honestly for the life of my could not come up with a sure answer. So I pose it to you instead;

If I have 2 documents (page.html and form.php), and I have included form.php in my page.html as so:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Home</title>
      <?php include 'form.php'; ?>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
        <FORM CONTENT HERE>

      </form>

      <div class="results">
      <p><?php echo $result_variable ?></p>
      </div>
   </body>
 <script>
    !-- Ajax function here, POSTs to form.php
 </script>

</html>
```

Which has an AJAX form, POSTing to form.php, and a field for results, that prints the PHP variable $result_variable.

Now if My PHP page takes the posted data, after the initial document load / include has been completed - then changes the value of $result_variable as a result - will the value of $result_variable be updated within the page.html without the page reloading?

For example - if form.php looked something like this;

```
<?php
$result_variable = 1;

if (!empty($_POST)){
$result_variable = 2;
}

?>
```

After the initial pageload (without form submission), $result_variable should yeild 1. Though after the ajax form submission has been completed, the $result_variable has been changed to 2. Will this reflect without reloading page.html?

Thanks.

Comment: It will if your *Javascript* response handler from the AJAX request sets the response text to the `<p>` tag for your `$result_variable`. It won't happen magically, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Do you have any reading I could take a look at on how to handle the AJAX request in a similar fashion to complete the above task?

Comment: Unfortunately, the vast majority of the examples will be [jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6570220/451969). But in the page, you would use a (unique) `id` like `<p id='destination'...` and then in the response handler set the `document.getElementById('destination').textContent = response;`, `response` being what was returned from the script.

Comment: Here's a live [jQuery form submit example](http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/). jQuery does make Ajax a far simpler process, but I'd still suggest trying out the native method so you know what it's doing.

Comment: Perfect. Cheers for that, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. since `$result_variable` is not part of the current page that includes form.php.

It will only work if you populate it using javascript.

Let's say:

ajax targets form.php, so this is what form.php should look like:

```
<?php

  $result_variable = 1;

  if(!empty($_POST)){
    $result_variable = 2;
  }

  // print the result as an ajax response (the format here is not JSON)
  echo $result_variable;

  // if the response format is JSON
  echo json_encode(array("result_key_name" => $result_variable));
?>
```

Here's an example using jQuery `$.post` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
// on a normal php/html page
$.post("form.php", form_data, function(data){
   // data is the result echoed using json_encode() from form.php
   alert(data.result_key_name); // as per the server-side example above
}, "json");
```

Comment: Great thanks! Do you have anything I could read into on how to achieve reflect the changes, either through the Javascript response handler (from the AJAX request) or via other means?

Comment: Do you use jQuery for the ajax?

Comment: Not at the moment, though I'm happy to look into it.