# What is the ( best | fast ) way to get multiple HTTP Request Header In PHP

Tags: javascript, php, header, request

Example : But, loading pages really slow.

Any other PHP code or JavaScript.

My example code in PHP:

```
<?php
$aaalink = 'http://www.bbc.com/news';
function aaa_get_http_response($aaalink) {$headers = get_headers($aaalink);return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);}
$aaa_get_http_response = aaa_get_http_response($aaalink);
if ( $aaa_get_http_response == 200 ) 
{
echo $aaalink;
} 
else 
{echo "404";}
?>

<br>

<?php
$bbblink = 'http://www.independent.ie/news/';
function bbb_get_http_response($bbblink) {$headers = get_headers($bbblink);return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);}
$bbb_get_http_response = bbb_get_http_response($bbblink);
if ( $bbb_get_http_response == 200 ) 
{
echo $bbblink;
} 
else 
{echo "404";}
?>

<br>

<?php
$ccclink = 'http://www.rediff.com/news';
function ccc_get_http_response($ccclink) {$headers = get_headers($ccclink);return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);}
$ccc_get_http_response = ccc_get_http_response($ccclink);
if ( $ccc_get_http_response == 200 ) 
{
echo $ccclink;
} 
else 
{echo "404";}
?>
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: When you generate the page on server side (php), it is done by a single thread, so all the requests are done in a serial fashion (the second request starts only after the first one was completed). What you can do is create multiple threads that do these requests (each thread on request). Not sure in php how to do it, but as a general idea.

Comment: @Andrei Neagu But i can't do that .. unfortunately i have one page .. Thanks .

Comment: Inside that page, can't you create 3 threads and each one do it's request? I am thinking of a flow like this:

1) create 3 threads
2) run the 3 requests on each thread
3) wait for all 3 to complete
4) write the 3 responses
5) continue with the rest of the page stuff.
6) page goes back to client

. I think there should be something in php that allows you to do this.

Comment: Yes of course , But just with php code or javascript i have a wordpress theme . Thanks for your explanation :)

Comment: Then run the requests from javascript (it is async by nature, so the page will not be blocked). And as soon as you get a response, you render it. with jquery, you would run 3 $.ajax / $.get requests. Here is an example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The `get_headers` will wait until the requested website responds, the network quality matters. `aaa/bbb/ccc_get_http_response` is the same, use a `foreach` loop instead.