# How to retrieve the contents of PHP page in HTML page?

Tags: php, html, client-server

I'm trying to implement the following architecture using example of finding even/odd number. I'm using client as HTML file and web server as PHP.

[image: Simple HTTP Request]
[image]

**[ "FindEO.html" ] - The HTML file is shown below:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h3>Check Even/ODD Number</h3>
  <form method="get" action="http://192.168.0.103:81/DUNNO/eo.php">
    Enter number: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**[ "EO.php" ] - The PHP file is as follows:**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    $name = $_GET['fname'];
    $num = (int)$name;
    if (($num%2)==0) {
        echo "$name is Even";
    } else {
        echo "$name is Odd!";
    }   
} 
?>
```

When the **HTML** file is executed, it ask for input as:

[image]

After clicking on the submit button.
The **PHP** page is displayed rather than showing content of the **PHP** page inside the **HTML** file.

**[ Currently showing (PHP file): ]**

[image]

**[ It should show PHP content in HTML File ]**

[image]

So, the request is sent from HTML file to PHP server, and instead of getting response from PHP file to HTML file, it is showing directly the PHP file itself.

1) *Is this possible to display the expected output. (PHP processed output in HTML file)?*

2) *Suppose I stored the current PHP code in function as:*

```
<?php
function findeo($num){
    if (($num%2)==0) {
        echo "$name is Even";
    } else {
        echo "$name is Odd!";
    } 
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    $name = $_GET['fname'];
    $num = (int)$name;
    findeo($num);
} 
?>
```

*then how to pass **parameter** (10 or any number to **$num** variable) and call the **findeo()** function of the **PHP** page inside the **HTML** file?*

Someone please help me to implement the client - server architecture or tell me if there as any other way where this architecture can work using **HTML** as **client** & **PHP** as **server**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP cannot modify the content of the page after it has been served to the browser. However this would be trivial with a JavaScript Library such as jQuery. or by using AJAX to call the php script to update an element. There are examples on StackOverFlow like: [Change DIV content using ajax, php and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery)

Comment: Thanks Alex, can you please explain little bit. Do I need to make changes in HTML file. If yes, then what. And how this PHP file will display it's output to HTML file.

Comment: PHP cannot modify the content of the page after it has been served to the browser. However this would be trivial with a JavaScript Library such as jQuery. or by using AJAX to call the php script to update an element. There are examples on StackOverFlow like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

Comment: Thank you so much Alex, I did saw your link & found copious solution.

Comment: please mark the updated answer as correct thank you

Answer (score 1):

use javascript to send the form to the php file and retrieve the answer.
here is how i would have done it:

```js
  function getAnswer(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://192.168.0.103:81/DUNNO/eo.php', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'text';

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById('answer').textContent = xhr.response;
            }
        }
    };
    
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      document.getElementById('answer').textContent = "Error...";
    }

    xhr.send(null);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h3>Check Even/ODD Number</h3>
  <form method="get" onsubmit="getAnswer(event)">
    Enter number: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  
  <div id="answer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

using preventDefault() will stop the page from trying to submit the form, and allow the javascript to perform the request by itself.
also, i added a div to your HTML that will hold the respone given by your PHP file.

Comment: Thanks Maor. I did used _XHR_ method & did some search how to execute it. But found that _XHR_ requires **CORS** (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) policy (which need to be done using IIS from client side) or **ActiveXObjects** need to be enabled to execute _XHR_ scripts.